# Select a node with condition on ancestors

Tags: xml, xpath

My problem : I need to check the attribute "attributeToBeTested" of "testElement". "testElement" is the only child of "test". One condition : this "test" element must be a child of "toto" and not a child of "tata" or "titi".

So I wrote my test as :

```
//toto/descendant::test/descendant::testElement[attribute::attributeToBeTested != "Z"] and //test[not(ancestor::tata)] and //test[not(ancestor::titi)]
```

What i think i wrote : give me all "test" elements, child of "toto", where the "attributeToBeTested" of the "testElement" element is not set at "Z" AND that doesn't have "tata" or "titi" as ancestor.

But apparently, this test is wrong and this is driving me crazy !

Here is the XML example :

```
<tata>
  ....
  <test>
      <testElement attributeTobeTested="Z"/>
  </test>
</tata>
<toto>
  ....
  <test>
      <testElement attributeTobeTested="H"/>
  </test>
  ....
  <test>
      <testElement attributeTobeTested="Z"/>  <---- This one should pop up
  </test>
</toto>    
<toto>
  ....
  <titi>
      <test>
          <testElement attributeTobeTested="Z"/>
      </test>
  </titi>
</toto>
```

Only one should pop up : the one inside the "toto" not in "tata" and not in "titi" and with attribute to "Z"

Comment: can you paste the source html or the public url if available?

Comment: It'a a rule i need to put on local XML

Comment: Share XML sample for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath:

```
//toto//test[not(ancestor::*[name()=("titi", "tata")])]/testElement[@attributeTobeTested="Z"]
```

It should return you required `testElement` node